# Android - fill edit text views from mysql database search

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, search

I am a total newbie to java so excuse me if this doesn't make sense. I am trying to make a simple android application where the user can enter in a department name and then click a search button. It will then retrieve data from the mysql database and populate edit text boxes underneath with that information.

So far I have the database connected to my app:

db.java

```
public class db {
public static Connection con;
public static void main(String[] argv) {
  try
    {
        connectionQuery();

        PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from buildings");/*write query inside of prepared statement*/
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("DataBase table accessed");

        while(result.next())
        {
           String retrievedid= result.getString("name");

           System.out.println(retrievedid);
        }


        con.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
    }
 }
public static void connectionQuery()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fypdb","root","");
        System.out.println("Remote DB connection established");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Remote server could not be connected");
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Remote server could not be connected");
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Remote db connection establishment error");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("False query");
    }

}
}
```

this is working fine and is printing out the results.

But now I don't know how to search the database from the application and populate the edit text views with the results.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `So far I have the database connected to my app:` ? Sorry but i do not see a connection from this code to an Android app. Is that code for an Android device? `this is working fine`. Is that already working fine in your Android app?

Answer (score 0):

first of all mysql database in not part of the operating system... if you manage to run then please let me know.. and also to google people...

android has support for SQLITE3 database you should try to use that for the betterment of android operating system

if i am wrong please correct me